# Put an optimization problem in QP form

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

I need to put the following optimization problem in QP form:
$$ \min_{x,y} \, c^Tx + b^T y +\lambda^T x + \frac{\rho}{2} \|x - \hat{x}\|^2 $$
where $\hat{x}$ is a const vec. The standard template for a QP problem appears to be
$$ \min_z \frac{1}{2}z^THz + f^T z $$
for some vec $f$, which doesn't appear to have room for a const vec.

I can't get this done unless I add $ \rho/2\|y - \hat{y}\|^2$ to the cost function of my problem but that doesn't feel right. Any help?
Thanks bunches.

Comment: Note that your problem is unbounded since you can drive the term related to $y$ arbitrarily negative. Hence you either have constraints in the model which you haven't revealed (which is fine since that is not relevant to the question) or you are missing a part in the objective.

Comment: The constraints are indeed present I was just lazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression expands to $\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}\rho I & 0\\0 &0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}c + \lambda-\rho\hat{x}\\b\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} + (\frac{\rho}{2} \hat{x}^T\hat{x})$

where the last term is constant and thus can be omitted without changing the optimal solution (only shifts the optimal objective)

Comment: It took me a few days to code this into MATLAB, but the final results turned out to be elegant and flawless. Thank you very much for your wonderful answer, which saved the day just in time! I'll remember this.